# Ambiguous column 'id' in ActiveRecord query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have somewhat complex ActiveRecord (2.3.8) models (not really, some associations and named scopes, and one cached value) and somewhere in my application I see the following MySQL (5.1) query appear:

```
SELECT `cases`.id FROM `cases`
INNER JOIN `contracts` ON `cases`.contract_id = `contracts`.id
WHERE ((case_status_id = 0 AND case_status_id IS NOT NULL) AND id = XXXX)
AND ((`cases`.`archived` = 0)
AND ((`contracts`.customer_id = XXXX)))
LIMIT 1
```

Obviously not the most readable query. Sometimes ActiveRecord complains that the column 'id' is ambiguous, and I have to agree :-)

This only happens however, when the data in the database is 'sparse'. We have an import script that fills up these tables, and the more data is inserted, the less frequent these errors become.

The code triggering the exception:

```
paginate_options = {:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25 }
options = paginate_options.merge(:include => [:active_status, :case_summary], :order => @sortable.order)
@cases = current_customer.cases.unarchived.paginate(options)
```

Where the 'active status' field is cached:

```
belongs_to    :active_status, 
            :class_name   => "CaseStatus", 
            :foreign_key  => 'case_status_id'
caches_value  :case_status_id, 
            :sql => 'SELECT id FROM case_statuses WHERE case_id = #{id} ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1'
```

The stacktrace looks like this:

```
config/initializers/connection_fix.rb:  17:in `execute'
vendor/plugins/cached_values/lib/cached_value.rb:  91:in `update_cache'
vendor/plugins/cached_values/lib/cached_value.rb:  14:in `load'
vendor/plugins/cached_values/lib/cached_values.rb:  85:in `case_status_id'
plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:  82:in `paginate'
plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/collection.rb:  85:in `create'
plugins/will_paginate/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:  76:in `paginate'
```

So I assume this error happens trying to refresh the cache for the first time. The query appears to be used by the cached_values plugin and inside a will_paginate statement, but the cached query used in that statement does not appear in the query above.

I also do not understand why ActiveRecord would query `cases.id` when there is also an `id=XXXX` statement. I assume both query the same `id`, but then again, it **is** quite ambiguous..

Any way I can tell ActiveRecord to use explicit table names? Or a way to debug the way this query is constructed? Is the 'cached_values' plugin maybe affected by named scopes and is there a way around that?

Comment: Can you show use the code that generates this query?

Comment: Included a snippet of the controller and the model.